# Animation on top of MapField in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I am using blackberry maps to write my Application and want to show current location of the user on the map using a Blue dot image. I am able to do it by overriding the paint() method of the MapField and place the image at the right place.

However now I want to pulsate(breathing bubble) the image, for that I am using a gif image with 3 different frames. Here i am not sure how to display all the 3 frames at certain frame rate so that I don't have to rely upon mapfield.paint() to draw my images. Initially I thought of using AnimatedGifField's thread for this, but not sure how to using it coz i can't add a field(AnimatedGifField) to a field(MapField). I am using JDE 6.0

Does anyone has any idea about it..?

Answer (score 2):

I would probably just keep using the paint() method, but when you need to redraw the bubble, invalidate a region instead of invalidating the entire screen. This will allow you to continue using the paint method without needing to have the entire thing redraw itself.

Comment: Wont't calling `MapField.invalidate(x, y, width, height)` trigger  `mapfield.paint()`..? What if i have to replace the current image(bitmap) with the next one, how/where should i specify that..?

Comment: Yeah it will, but the actual painting done will be limited to that region. I would just put all 3 bitmaps into an array and have some counter that cycles through them so you just paint `bubbles[frame]` then increment `frame`.

Comment: Problem for me in this approach is the paint() callback, since paint() method is called due to so many other reasons one of them is navigation on the map. And i draw a lot many icon/business address on the screen on this paint method. I am not sure how to differentiate between the normal pain() call and the one coming form invalidate(), also the overhead could be more. Do yo think my concern is correct..?

Comment: The issue you'll run into if you don't use `paint()` is that you may end up having your bubble leave a trail of itself on the map because of old pixels not being redrawn with the underlying map. It might make it choppy, but in your Thread that controls the drawing, you could put a `synchronized` block of code that first sets a drawingBubble flag, invalidates, and then resets the flag. The graphics object won't draw places that it doesn't think are dirty (trust me on this, it's given me headaches in the past), so invalidating a region is, I think, still the best option.